# Usage of FieldMask in proto 3

Tags: c++, design-patterns, protocol-buffers

I have a class named Model and a message Item which are defined as follow.

```
// C++ code
class Model
{
 string name;
 int id;
 string owner;
 // ... and so on
};

// .proto file
message Item
{
 string name = 1;
 int identity = 2;
 string holder =3;
 // ... and so on
 FieldMask mask = 30;
}
```

What's the best way/design to set the model from item updates.

I want to set only the specified fields in the mask.

The solution I have is :

```
::Item item;
Model model = getModel(); // get an existed model

for (auto& path : item.mask())
{
 if (path == "name")
  model.set_name(item.name());
 else if (path == "identity")
  model.set_id(item.identity());
// ... and so on
}
```

This solution is not efficient because I have to check all fields each time.

Is there a best solution for this problem or a best usage of the Field Mask Utility ?